Can't import my CurdRepository interface to my controller
I am learning Java spring boot and have programmed a basic REST API. Everything has worked so far. Since I have been in a VPN, the application no longer works. I get the following error message:
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.Registration required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.IUserRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.IUserRepository' in your configuration.

This cannot be due to the VPN. But I don't know what else it could be because everything looks right to me. Here is the program, with all files in one package, except the POM
class User:
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String prename;
    private String lastname;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private int age;
    
    public User() { }
    
    public User(String prename, String lastname, int age, String password, String email) {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.prename = prename;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.age = age;
    }
    
    //getter
    public String getID() {return id;}
    public String getPrename() { return prename;}
    public String getLastname() {return lastname;}
    public int getAge() {return age;}
    public String getEmail() {return email;}
    public String getPassword() {return password;}
    
    //setter
    public void setID(String id) {this.id = id;}
    public void setPrename(String prename) {this.prename = prename;}
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {this.lastname = lastname;}
    public void setAge(int age) {this.age = age;}
    public void setEmail(String email) {this.email = email;}
    public void setPassword(String password) {this.password = password;}
}

interface IUserRepository:
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface IUserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String>
{

}

class Registration (controller in short)
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

//import denniscompany.websitemodels.*;
//import denniscompany.websiterepositories.*;

@RestController
public class Registration {
    
    private IUserRepository userRepository;

    public Registration(IUserRepository p_oUserRepository ) {
        userRepository = p_oUserRepository;
        userRepository.save(new User("Test", "User", 28, "test@gmx.de", "1234"));
        
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public Iterable<User> getUsers() { return userRepository.findAll(); }
    

And my POM.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-B01</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.224</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

In Eclipse I do not get an error message that it could not compile. So hopefully someone could help me.
I have tried these solutions on this linkCan't Autowire @Repository annotated interface in Spring Boot
but it doesn't work. I tried to Autowire my repository and set to my interface the the annotation Repository. Additional I set to my main the annotation EnableJpaRepositories. But it gives me the same error. All files are in one package, so I dont need a scanComponent or scanEntity etc. The solution of my link is 9 years old and probably outdated.
I get an error in eclipse and a solution to import my interface. But when I click on it nothing happens. Probably because I can't import it, because it is in the same package. So I have muliple files in one package but they don't see each other.

Have you tried adding a dependency on spring-boot-starter-data-jpa? It seems a bit odd that you're trying to depend on jakarta.persistence-api directly - that's not what any of the example projects (or the empty projects generated by Spring Initializr) do.

I have read that jakarta is used in new projects. And I use java 17 an had trouble to import the Entity annotation.
Anyway I tried it out and get new errror:
Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


@Razielruss Jakarta just defines APIs, you need to specify which implementation to use (Hibernate, Eclipse Link, ...).  spring-boot-starter-data-jpa includes Hibernate by default, now you need to specify your datasource with URL, credentials, or add a dependency to an embeded DB like H2.

If you're using Spring Boot with the data JPA starter, it should scan and find your repositories.
If your repository is extending org.springframework.data.repository.Repository, you don't need to add the @Repository annotation.
Your issue is most likely in the dependencies and configuration. The main one is about which database are you using? MariaDB, Postgres, ...
You should add a dependency to your DB JDBC driver and define the datasource with URL and credentials.
If you don't have one set up yet and just want to test first, you can use an embedded DB like H2 by simply adding a dependency, then Spring boot will configure it for you. In your pom, the H2 dependency has the test scope so it won't be used when running your app.
Try the following:

Add spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency
Add your DB JDBC driver dependency (or add an embedded DB)
Configure your datasource in your Spring config file
Try again


Okay I solve it. thank you for your help.  I solve it as follow:
I included the JPA dependency and changed the scope of the h2 dependency to runtime.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.224</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

With that I should have an embedded Database and an URL in my config is not needed
The next important point is my package hierarchy. My subpackeges have to be under my packag where my main class is. Like that:
com.example.application->main.java
com.example.application.controller-> my controller
com.example.application.repositories->my Repo
com.example.application.models -> my Model User

With this hierarchy I don't need componentScan. The annotation SpringBootApplication does for me.
When I have a package sturcutre like
com.example.application->main.java
com.example.controller-> my controller
com.example.repositories->my Repo
com.example.models -> my Model User

Than my main need the following scan annotations
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repositories")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.controllers")
@EntityScan("com.example.models")

Than it will work too.
Last but not least I had to change my model User to Customer. I am not sure but the word "User" is a key word in some databases like H2(maybe) and postgres(for sure). So I have to changed it to make my applications works.
I hope this post will help some java spring boot beginners
